# Load a route with varying optional parameters in ember

Tags: ember.js

We want to load a single route with varying optional parameters. Example

Route A is "abc"
Route B is "123"

In one scenario we want to load B by passing parameter x from A so route B would be 123/:x.
other scenario we want to load B by passing parameter y and z from A so route B would be 123/:y/:z

Is it possible?

Comment: Can you explain better what you are trying to acomplish? I don't quite understand, also please show some code of what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

A route cannot have a varying number of dynamic segments, which is the correct term for what you call "parameters". How could it? There is only one path parameter. However, you could specify two routes B1 and B2, one with a single dynamic segment and one with two, and then arrange your code, perhaps via mechanisms such as class inheritance, so whatever code needs to be is shared.